# Test code to catch the box

Tags: html5-canvas

I created a test problem of canvas I could not. falling from the top box into the box below thought moving would like to bring an event occurs. Thank you for helping

http://jsbin.com/imitiv/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand.

How to move bottom box left/right with keystrokes

```
// new stuff -- put this just before your init()
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyd, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyu, false);
```

How to test if top rectangle is hitting bottom rectangle

```
function hit(rect1, rect2) {
  return (rect1.x <= rect2.x + rect2.r &&
          rect2.x <= rect1.x + rect1.r &&
          rect1.y <= rect2.y + rect2.r &&
          rect2.y <= rect1.y + rect1.r)
}
```